# How can I set document.getElementById(...) is null massage to true

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, isnull

I have more document.getElementById in my code, but when I run my code, just two document.getElementById (ctx1, ctx2) get values the others not. How can I reach that the others (in my case ctx3)  return true and I do not get error massage. Here is my demo code:

**DEMO**

```
var ctx1=document.getElementById("data1").getContext("2d");     
var ctx2 =document.getElementById("data2").getContext("2d");
var ctx3 =document.getElementById("data3").getContext("2d");
```

In this case ctx1 and ctx2 get value but the ctx3 not, that's why I got the *document.getElementById(...) is null* error message in the console. I have some attempt but these are failed.

**ATTEMPT**

***1***

```
if(ctx3 === null || 
   ctx3 === undefined) {
    return true;
}
```

***2***

```
if(document.getElementById("data3")..getContext("2d").value == null){
    return true;
  }
```

Comment: Please post the HTML.

Comment: use `typeof document.getElementById("yourid") !== 'undefined'`

Comment: @bRIMOs: `typeof null` is `"object"`, not `"undefined"`, and there's no need for a `typeof` check here at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If an element with that ID may not exist, you need to break up your statement. You can't do this:

```
// Not this
var ctx3 =document.getElementById("data3").getContext("2d");
```

...because `document.getElementById("data3")` may return `null`, and then you get an error trying to use that for `.getContext("2d")`. So instead:

```
var elm3 = document.getElementById("data3");
var ctx3 = elm3 && elm3.getContext("2d");
```

Now, if there is no `id="data3"` element in your document, `elm3` and `ctx3` will both be `null`. If there is, `elm3` will refer to the element and `ctx3` to the 2D context.

If you're going to do this more than once, you could give yourself a function for it:

```
function getOptionalContext(id) {
    var elm = document.getElementById(id);
    return elm && elm.getContext("2d");
}
```

Then:

```
var ctx1 = getOptionalContext("data1");
var ctx2 = getOptionalContext("data2");
var ctx3 = getOptionalContext("data3");
```

---

Side note: Any time you find yourself writing `var1`, `var2`, `var3`, ..., consider using an array instead.

Answer (score 0):

If `document.getElementById("data1")` is `undefined`, `( document.getElementById("data1") != null )` will give `false`. In this case, you can easily skip the `getContext("2d")` if they are `undefined`. Hope this helps.

```
var ctx1 = ( document.getElementById("data1") != null ) ? ( document.getElementById("data1") != null ).getContext("2d") : null;
var ctx2 = ( document.getElementById("data2") != null ) ? ( document.getElementById("data2") != null ).getContext("2d") : null; 
var ctx3 = ( document.getElementById("data3") != null ) ? ( document.getElementById("data3") != null ).getContext("2d") : null;
```

Comment: Code dumps are not *useful* answers. Say *what* you did, and *why*.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above by others, the error occurs because `.getElementById(...)` method returns null if there is no element with such an ID. And you can't call methods on `null`, because it has no corresponding built-in class (for example, numbers have `Number` built-in class and that's why you can call methods like `3.0.toFixed()` ).
Taking into account great suggestion of [T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder)  about using an array, here is my code:

```
var selectors = ["data1", "data2", "data3"];
var contexts = selectors.map(function(selector) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(selector);
    return elem ? elem.getContext("2d") : true;
});
```

This will return an array of contexts (if element is not present, on the place of its context in the array, `true` will be present)